# Applications that Integrate with Oracle's PeopleSoft Enterprise Human Capital Management

Tags: oracle, api, peoplesoft

I work with an engineering team that's built an enterprise-class web application. Currently, the application allows direct importing of business employees/users by uploading .csv files - but we're looking into alternative methods.

One alternative is somehow building an integration with Oracle's PeopleSoft Enterprise Human Capital Management system. We have very little experience with Oracle products, has anyone attempted to integrate an application with PeopleSoft HCMS? Any advice/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle PeopleSoft allows several methods of integration including Web services (SOAP and, with PeopleTools 8.52, REST). The component is called Integration Broker.

I work with applications that have SOAP/REST services available and PeopleSoft sends web service calls to these applications to add/update users and other data. If you are able to build a web service and generate a WSDL, PeopleSoft can import that structure and use it to build the web service, however you will need PeopleSoft development in order to complete the integration.

Hope this helps
John